Does $K_L^0 ​→π^+π^−$ violate strangeness and/or parity?
The long-lived neutral Kaon $K_L^0$ is a superposition of $K^0$ and its antiparticle $\overline{K^0}$. Thus, I would say the strangeness is 0 on both sides. However, if we draw the corresponding Feynman Diagrams, wouldn't we need two? One for the case where the $K_L^0$ is a $K^0$ and one where it is a $\overline{K^0}$? In these two diagrams, the strangeness would be violated.
Overall, as this happens via the weak interaction, I think parity should be violated for sure.
I am a little bit confused on how to handle superpositions of particles. Any clarification is highly appreciated.

For the record: quantum counting numbers like strangeness, charmness, topness, bottomness etc. are all violated by the decay of those quarks (i.e. weak decay of a gen-2 quark into a gen-1 quark, or a gen-3 quark into a gen-2 quark). As far as I know those numbers aren't generally conserved, although the underlying charges (electric charge, color charge, weak isospin/charge, spin, and total energy) are all conserved.

this may be useful http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/kaon.html

@controlgroup FYI the conserved quantum numbers for fermions in the standard model are baryon number and lepton number. Flavor for both quarks and leptons is not conserved -- meaning that strangeness, charmness, etc for quarks, and electron-ness, muon-ness, etc for leptons, is not conserved (the latter would be conserved if neutrinos were massless or at least if the off-diagonal elements of the PMNS matrix were zero). Also charges associated with unbroken gauge symmetries are conserved (electric charge, color charge). Interactions with the Higgs break weak isospin because of SSB.

And energy-momentum and angular momentum are conserved, but not spin. For example, 1 neutral spin-$0$ pion $\pi^0$ can decay into two spin-$1$ photons via $\pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma + \gamma$. Although, of course, total angular momentum is conserved.

That’s what I was trying to get across, thank you for the clarification @Andrew.

Indeed, the long-lived neutral Kaon $^0_$
is a symmetric superposition of $^0$ with strangeness -1 and its antiparticle $\bar{}  ^0$ with strangeness 1.

Thus, I would say the strangeness is 0 on both sides.

No: Applying the strangeness operator on it, you see it is not a strangeness eigenstate and so it has no well-defined strangeness. It flips into its short partner.

However, if we draw the corresponding Feynman Diagrams, wouldn't we need two? In these two diagrams, the strangeness would be violated.

Indeed, if you draw the weak decay diagrams for $\bar s d$ and $\bar d s$, strangeness and parity is violated in each.
Ignoring CP violation which is irrelevant here, you see that a doubly weak box diagram leads to strangeness oscillations from $^0$    to  $\bar{} ^0$ and vice-versa.
The decay of your title violates CP, but you do not seem to be asking about that. The discussion in Griffith's text, Section 4.4.3.1 is quite clear.
